# error creating a child node in firebase with ios app swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a set a chat app in firebase so what I want is to retrieve the list of chat in which the current user has interacted.

[image: database structure here]

I'm trying to create a child node with an specific id "id-id" with this.

```
messages.append(message)
        let current = ref.child(message.sender.id + "-" + (self.compi?.id!.description)!)
        let messageref = current.childByAutoId().key
        current.child(messageref).setValue(message)
```

the id of the child in database is like in pic 11-126 where 11 is the id of one user and 126 is the id of the other user. but the creation of the child return

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100be7708)

How do I make a child that does not exist.

Comment: There isn't enough information on the error to determine exactly what's happening, but my guess based on what you've shown here is that somewhere the code is unwrapping an optional in the line `let current = ref.child(message.sender.id + "-" + (self.compi?.id!.description)!)`. I recommend printing `compi`, `compi?.id?`, and `compi?.id?.description` before that line to see if any of them are `nil`.

Comment: you may be right i change to  ref.child("\(message.sender.id)-\(self.compi!.id!")) and get it works